# JAX-RS support for file upload

Tags: rest, jersey, resteasy

I researched ways to write a file upload application. The examples either make use of Jersey or RESTEasy specific annotations to implement the application.

Is there no support for a file upload in the JAX-RS spec itself? Do I have to import Jersey or RESTEasy specific classes to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could develop your own JAX-RS impl-agnostic Multipart support (develop a JAX-RS message-body reader/writer and your own Java representation of the multipart entity) - essentially duplicating what Jersey or RESTEasy provide through their proprietary API already, if JAX-RS portability is of high importance to you.